# JS apply only for first element

Tags: javascript, php

I need some help to apply js code for all elements, but for now works only for first on each page.

On page are items with buy buttons, that is created by script, so all buttons have same id but is more than one of them - and I can't apply script that disable button if some condition, only work for first button.

```
    <?php $elem = getElement('button_basket'); ?>
    <button disabled = "true" onclick = "checkInput(event)" id="b1" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block tobasket <?php echo $elem['content_tr'] ?>" product_id="<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $prdata['full_name'] ?>" nametr="<?php echo $prdata['name1_tr'] ?>" url="<?php echo $cur_url; ?>catalog/<?php echo $v['img_url']; ?>" price="<?php echo $v['price']; ?>" <?php if($v['sold']==1) echo 'sold="true"'; ?>><?php echo $elem['content'] ?></button>
    <?php $elem = getElement('button_oneclick'); ?>
    <p class="prod-oneclick <?php echo $elem['content_tr'] ?>" <?php if($v['sold']==1) echo 'sold="true"'; ?>><?php echo $elem['content'] ?></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkInput(event){

    
    <?php
$cookie_basket = $_COOKIE['basket'];    
$tempo = urlencode($cookie_basket);
$countChars = mb_strlen($tempo);
//echo $countChars;
    ?>
let test = '<?php echo $countChars;?>';
let btncheck = document.querySelectorAll('[disabled]');
//      var step;
//      for (step = 0; step < 5; step++) {
if (test > 80){
  document.getElementById("b1").disabled = true;
}else{
  document.getElementById("b1").disabled = false;
}
    }
//  window.onload = checkInput(event);
//  }
</script>
```

if will need can provide full page script.

Comment: "_so all buttons have same id_" `id` attributes need to be _unique_ on a page

Comment: yep, i have item list page that is created like - product id + button - product id + button, button code is one in script(so is same button)

Comment: Also, I would suggest you select with a `class` name rather than `disabled` property.

Comment: at start  was selecting by class '.tobasket'

Comment: [link](http://testweb.parfumanalog.com/ru/katalog/zhenshchinam) all buttons is created with same code and have same is, how to apply code for all of them?

Comment: Also, when `test > 80`, it seems like you want nothing to happen: the button is disabled, and you keep it disabled... If that is truly the only thing you do, then don't bind the event in case `$countChars > 80`.

Comment: test > 80 is checking condition, and working(if cookie char more than 80 -> disable button, working, but is working only for first button, all next button not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use data attributes and delegation

Also your script can be vastly simplified

```js
let test = '<?php echo $countChars;?>';

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[disabled]')].forEach(btn => btn.disabled = test > 80)
});
```

```html
<?php
$cookie_basket = $_COOKIE['basket'];    
$tempo = urlencode($cookie_basket);
$countChars = mb_strlen($tempo);
?>

  <button disabled class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block tobasket <?php echo $elem['content_tr'] ?>" data-product_id="<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $prdata['full_name'] ?>" data-nametr="<?php echo $prdata['name1_tr'] ?>" data-url="<?php echo $cur_url; ?>catalog/<?php echo $v['img_url']; ?>"
    data-price="<?php echo $v['price']; ?>" <?php if($v[ 'sold']==1) echo 'data-sold="true"'; ?>><?php echo $elem['content'] ?></button>

  <p class="prod-oneclick <?php echo $elem['content_tr'] ?>" <?php if($v[ 'sold']==1) echo 'data-sold="true"'; ?>>
    <?php echo $elem['content'] ?>
  </p>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'test' has already been declared

Comment: [link](http://testweb.parfumanalog.com/ru/katalog/zhenshchinam?page=0)

Comment: A typo. btn.disabled = test should be btn.disabled == test

Comment: @jeff No. I assign true or false depending on test > 80

Answer (score 0):

Final code, fully working for me was:

```
<script>
function beCheerful() {
<?php
$cookie_basket = $_COOKIE['basket'];    
$tempo = urlencode($cookie_basket);
$countChars = mb_strlen($tempo);
?>  
let test = '<?php echo $countChars;?>';
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[disabled]')].forEach(btn => btn.disabled = test > 80)
});

}
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    beCheerful();
}
window.onload = beCheerful;
</script>
```